# Is there any R function to replace "part" of factor in column?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, data-cleaning, substitution

â‚¬0
â‚¬100K
â‚¬105K
â‚¬10K
â‚¬110K

Here in above is the head of the column in dataframe. And it is a factor. I want to remove 'â‚¬' this part from the complete column.But after trying to replace using the substitute function, it is changing to character and giving the values as "0","100K","105k","10k","110k".Help me on this.

```
fb$Wage = sub('â‚¬','',fb$Wage)
fb$Wage
```

Comment: Reconvert to factor: `factor(sub('â‚¬','',fb$Wage))`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `levels` and not the values of the `factor`:

```
levels(x) <- sub('â‚¬','', levels(x))
x
#[1] 0    100K 105K 10K  110K
#Levels: 0 100K 105K 10K 110K
```

Data:

```
x <- factor(c("â‚¬0", "â‚¬100K", "â‚¬105K", "â‚¬10K", "â‚¬110K"))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `fct_recode`

```
library(forcats)
library(stringr)
fct_recode(x, !!!setNames(levels(x), str_remove_all(levels(x), "[^[:ascii:]]+")))
#[1] 0    100K 105K 10K  110K
#Levels: 0 100K 105K 10K 110K
```

#### data

```
x <- factor(c("â‚¬0", "â‚¬100K", "â‚¬105K", "â‚¬10K", "â‚¬110K"))
```

Comment: what if i want to remove k also? @akrun

Comment: @SaiNikhilKataru that is easy i.e. `fct_recode(x, !!!setNames(levels(x), str_remove_all(levels(x), "\\D+")))#[1] 0   100 105 10  110
Levels: 0 100 105 10 110`